# Infinite scrolling in laravel 5

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-5, infinite-scroll

I am using infinitescrolling in laravel with pagination. I have 8 records my records limit is 4. Pagination working fine. Pagination link is coming with 2 page(4 *4 pages). But now i want to use infinite scrolling.

For infinite scroll i am using https://github.com/infinite-scroll/infinite-scroll

I have included jquery.infinitescroll.min.js in view page. and write script. **But by scroll down no any effect comes.**

**My View page :**

```
             <div class="content" id="content">
                @foreach($item['hits'] as $key => $data )
                   @include('general::partials.product-list')
                @endforeach
             </div>
                {!!$item->render()!!}
```

**My script :**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('/themes/'.Theme::getCurrent().'/js/jquery.infinitescroll.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    var loading_options = {
        finishedMsg: "<div class='end-msg'>Congratulations! You've reached the end of the internet</div>",
        msgText: "<div class='center'>Loading news items...</div>",
        img: "/assets/img/ajax-loader.gif"
    };

    $('#content').infinitescroll({
        loading: loading_options,
        navSelector: "ul.pagination",
        nextSelector: "ul.navigation a:first",
        itemSelector: "#content div.cat-item"
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems your script is not loaded yet when you're trying to execute it. Use this construction:

```
$( document ).ready()
```

It will run the code only when all JS files will be loaded.

Comment: Go to browser, check output HTML (not code inspector) and look at part where Laravel generates link to `jquery.infinitescroll.min.js`. Is this link code correct?

Comment: it create link before my script function.

Comment: Yes, but is the link is correct? It seems browser doesn't load `jquery.infinitescroll.min.js`.

Comment: yes the link is correct by open that link i can see the code of that js file in browser

Comment: Ok, try to load your script in master layout (not just in includes or partials), so it will always loads with any page. Also, use `$(document).ready()`

Comment: yes thanks it done i have added it in footer layout. But the infinite scrolling efect not working.  I am gettong 4 items. and by scroll down nothing happen. no any error

Comment: Great. You fixed the error and now you should look at your JS code which runs `infinitescroll()`. If you'll not find a solution you should post another question with all important code.